# Solving a Bidiagonal System in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix of the following form:

```
d1  0  0  0  0   0  0       x1        b1
a1 d2  0  0  0   0  0       x2        b2
0  a2  d3 0  0   0  0       x3        b3
0   0  a3 d4 a4  0  0   *   x4   =    b4
0   0  0  0  d5  a5 0       x5        b5
0   0  0  0  0   d6 a6      x6        b6
0   0  0  0  0   0  d7      x7        b7
```

I need to write a code to solve this system without forward elimination. I was assuming you could just solve for `x7 = b7/d7`. Then solve for `d6` by setting `d6 = b6-a6*x7 = b6-a6*(b7/d7)` from our first iteration... then carrying the rest backwards to the first row. However, I am experiencing a block:

1) How to hardcore the confusing differences in indices

2) How to start from a reverse order down from `d7` up to the first equation

3) Moreover, how do I generalize this for any system of `n`? According to personal readings I am doing for recreation, `n` is odd.

Can anyone assist me in coding this?

EDIT: The coefficient matrix is `A`, the `x` column vector can be denoted as `X`, and the `b` column vector can be denoted as `B` for convenience if needed.

Comment: Just to be sure: you don't want to use the built-in backslash operator, i.e. save yourself some hassle and write `X = A\B`?

Answer (score 1):

Let `A` be your `n`-by-`n` bi-diagonal matrix and `B` your right-hand-side of the equation. You can solve using this loop:

```
n = size(A,1);
x = zeros(n,1); %// pre-allocate for solution x
x(n) = B(n)/A(n,n); %// get the last element
for ii=(n-1):-1:1
    x(ii) = (B(ii)-x(ii+1)*A(ii,ii+1))/A(ii,ii); %// iteratively solve
end
```

---

Of course, it is always best to use built-in functions

```
x = A\B;
```